# Sublime Text 2 PHP syntax colour missing

Tags: php, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-plugin

For some reason `Sublime` is not loading syntax color's for `PHP` files, but seems working fine with other files (i.e. `HTML`).

How can i fix the problem? I have already tried to restart the app but nothing changes.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Try to manualy change syntax in bottom right corner.

Comment: it's already on php and if i try to change it to other languages they work fine, but php does not give me any colour. :-/ @Aleksandar

Comment: hmm, try to install 1337 color scheme from package control

Comment: Did you close and re-open the file? The syntax highlighting doesn't work on my Sublime installation after I've created a new PHP file until I do that.

Comment: @Marco Have you tried re-installing the application? I'm also wondering since when did this happen? From the beginning? From when malware Foo infected your PC?

Comment: I had similar issue with some sidebar package. Maybe packages have conflict. Try to uninstall some packages you installed recently.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandar , I gonna try to install the color scheme you suggested now

Comment: @sjagr yes I have tried to open/close file & sublime, nothing changes

Comment: @HamZa I was forced to restart the system because of an apple update last week, and only now i have notice this issue. I haven't got any virus as far as i know :)